# how to update every row with time/date diff MySQL with different format?

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna make some app with feeds/post feature. and my problem is i wanna make it with php to update my timeDiff column in mysql with '2 years ago' or '5 seconds ago' or '1 hour ago' depends on how old the post it is. currently i just have timeDiff using timestampdiff with seconds format.
current table example:

| name | timePost | timeDiff |
|:---- |:------| :-----|
| Bobby  | 2020-6-7 10:40:26| 74059449|
| Glenn  | 2021-10-11 21:32:11| 39597944|
| Yerch  | 2022-10-12 12:45:57| 7118|
query in php:
`UPDATE story SET timeDiff = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, timePost, NOW())`

Expected table example:
| name | timePost | timeDiff |
|:---- |:------|:-----|
| Bobby  | 2020-6-7 10:40:26| 2 years ago|
| Glenn  | 2021-12-11 21:32:11| 11 months ago|
| Yerch  | 2022-10-12 12:45:57| 2 hours ago|

any idea how to make it? Any help will be very valuable. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to store this data? Why not calculate this in your application on displaying the data?

Comment: i dont know im a beginner, is that will be better i calculate in my app instead of in my api?

Comment: If you write this text to the database, you need to update this for all elements each second, as the row that currently holds "5 seconds ago" is some moments later "6 seconds ago"

Comment: not in my database,  i want to make it with php.

Comment: What do you mean by "not in my database"? Updating a database column always happens in the database

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do that in database. Instead, store `created` field and use something like [this function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/human_time_diff/) in your PHP script.

Comment: but i wanna save it to the database for every single row with php

Comment: Why would you want to save that? If you save now that `row 1` is `5 seconds old` and `row 2` is `2 minutes old`, that information is wrong after 1 minute. You would have to update this information for all rows constantly. If you need that time only when displaying the row, then the frontend surely is the correct place to calculate it.

Comment: yeah its already solved. i'm convert it on my app instead in database thank you.